# Accented character incorrectly encoding in NSString Array

Tags: ios, encoding, nsstring, nsmutablearray

?I'm building a NSMutableArray of NSStrings from a list and some of the letters are accented (Turkish). I have been able to encode into a NSString and NSLog the results. But when I add that NSString to my NSMutableArray the encoding is incorrect.

This works:

```
NSString* temp = [[NSString alloc] init];
char *str = "üç"; 
temp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"üç"];
NSLog(@"str: %@",temp);
```

Logged output:

```
2012-06-09 09:09:18.398 Fluent[1821:f803] str: üç
```

When I try to add it to my NSMutableArray like this:

```
ones = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"bir",@"iki",temp,@"dört",@"beş",@"altı",@"yedi",@"sekiz",@"dokuz",nil];
NSLog(@"ones: %@",ones);
```

It loses the encoding:

```
2012-06-09 09:09:18.399 Fluent[1821:f803] ones: (
"",
bir,
iki,
"\U00fc\U00e7",
"d\U00f6rt",
"be\U015f",
"alt\U0131",
yedi,
sekiz,
dokuz)
```

Any ideas on how to do this? The posts I have read around this area seem to be focused on transfer over HTTP.

I'd like a simpler approach such as to encode a C-string if this is necessary and then unstring by spaces into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings aren't incorrectly encoded. What you see is an artifact of writing a complete array to the log. In this case, the array is first converted to the property list format and then written to the log.

If you create a loop and write each element separately to the log, you'll see that everything is ok:

```
NSUInteger count = [ones count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"element %d: %@", i, [ones objectAtIndex: i]);
}
```

Comment: You are correct. In fact I didn't need the `stringWithUTF8String` encoding at all, the usual @"" works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Output: `element 3: üç
 element 4: dört`

Answer (score 1):

This is not losing the encoding, try to add the strings from the nsarray to a UILabel or UITextField and it should be correct
This behavior of writing the Unicode representation happens only in the console when you NSLog

Comment: You are right: they do display correctly in the UILabel. Thanks!